Items.Restrict not consistently working across different values of datetime. ( Excel VBA, MS Outlook)
I am fetching emails within a timeframe from MS Outlook to populate a sheet of Excel.
Using Items.Restrict(filterstring) to constrain the results to between two datetime stamps.
This works for intervals like 6/14/2024 23:59 and 6/15/2024 23:59 (daylong) returning the count of incoming Outlook items (emails, meeting invites, reports, etc.).
Intervals like 6/15/2024 4:50 and 6/15/2024 23:59 incorrectly return 0 results, as validated against Outlook.
'Has the nescessary Outlook variable declarations and references. DateTime vars strT and EndT

restrictfilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(CStr(strtT), "M/D/YYYY h:n") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(CStr(EndT), "M/D/YYYY h:n") & "'"
Set olItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(restrictfilter)
allitemscount = olItems.Count


Please check the values you get from the format method. What value type are strtT and EndT? You may try to remove CStr there.

Include AMPM in the format.
Option Explicit

Private Sub ExtractEmail_Time()

    Dim olFolder As folder
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim restrictfilter As String
    Dim olItems As Items
    
    Dim allItemsCount As Long
    
    Set olFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Dim strtT As Date
    Dim endT As Date
    
    strtT = "6/15/2024 4:50"
    endT = "6/15/2024 23:59"
    
    restrictfilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(CStr(strtT), "M/D/YYYY h:n") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(CStr(endT), "M/D/YYYY h:n") & "'"
    Set olItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(restrictfilter)
    allItemsCount = olItems.count
    Debug.Print allItemsCount
    
    restrictfilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(CStr(strtT), "M/D/YYYY h:n ampm") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(CStr(endT), "M/D/YYYY h:n ampm") & "'"
    Set olItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(restrictfilter)
    allItemsCount = olItems.count
    Debug.Print allItemsCount
    
    restrictfilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(strtT, "M/D/YYYY h:n ampm") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(endT, "M/D/YYYY h:n ampm") & "'"
    Set olItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(restrictfilter)
    allItemsCount = olItems.count
    Debug.Print allItemsCount
    
    restrictfilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(strtT, "ddddd h:n ampm") & "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(endT, "ddddd h:n ampm") & "'"
    Set olItems = olFolder.Items.Restrict(restrictfilter)
    allItemsCount = olItems.count
    Debug.Print allItemsCount
    
End Sub


Use format string that returns 2 digit for hour, minute, day, and month: "MM/DD/YYYY hh:nn"
